# Why does SVG with image inside it have a bunch of whitespace on top

Tags: svg

I have a jpeg that does not have any whitespace on top

I put it as a child of an SVG

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   width="250"
   height="500">
    <image
      x="0"
      y="0"
      width="250"
      height="500" 
      href="https://assets.codepen.io/1281712/little-nemo-19051126-l.jpeg"  />
</svg>
```

and I end up with about 80px whitespace before the display of the image.
This happens in both Firefox and Chrome.

If I inspect the image element I am told it is 250 by 500.

Here is the codepen showing the issue
https://codepen.io/bryanrasmussen/pen/NWgWBYG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The white space at the top and bottom is padding so the image can keep its aspect ratio.

The image's native size is 1738 x 2378, which is roughly a ratio of 3 to 4.

By specifying a width and height of 250 and 500 for the image, you are creating an area with a ratio of 1 to 2. So in order to fit the image without distorting it, it is scaled to a width of 250 and then padded at the top an bottom to achieve a height of 500.

To remove the padding, only specify the width:

```
<image x="0" y="0" width="250" href="https://assets.codepen.io/1281712/little-nemo-19051126-l.jpeg"></image>
```

Comment: I guess could also put preserveAspectRatio="none" on it if I didn't care to preserve.

Comment: Yes, there are many other options, incl. the one you're proposing. It depends on whether you want to remove the padding or scale the image to a specific size.